# How to create filter with easy way in laravel 8 using controller and checkbox

Tags: laravel, filter, laravel-8

I am creating filter for the products, I tried using jquery for this before but I am not able to fix the pagination in laravel. So, I am trying this to fix the pagination as well as reduce the database query, bcoz in jquery everytime I click on any category or sub category, then it hits the database so the number of execution was more, So I replace the jquery and trying to use the button to do the same. But stuck with the array.

**Can anyone help me with this?**

```
$category = ["p1","p2","p3"];
$sub_category = ["c1","c2","c3","c4"];
$data = [];
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($cate as $category){
        $data2 =[];
        $count1 = 0;
        foreach ($sub_cate as $sub){
            $data2[] = [
                'sub_category_id' => $category.$count1++,
                'sub_category' => $sub,
                'url' => $category.'|'.$sub
            ];
        }
        $data[] = [
            'category_id' => 'category_'.$count++,
            'category' => $category,
            'sub_category' => $data2
        ];
    }
```

In blade file :

```
@foreach($filters as $filter)
   <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2">
       <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input category_filter1" id={{$filter["category_id"]}} name="category_filter[]" value="{{$filter["category"]}}">
       <label class="custom-control-label w-100" for="{{$filter["category_id"]}}">{{$filter["category"]}}</label>
        @foreach($filter["sub_category"] as $sub)
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mb-2">
                 <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input category_filter1" id={{$sub["sub_category_id"]}} name="sub_category_filter[]" value="{{$sub["url"]}}">
                 <label class="custom-control-label w-100" for="{{$sub["sub_category_id"]}}">{{$sub["sub_category"]}}</label>
            </div>
         @endforeach
   </div>
@endforeach
```

After using this code I am getting this type of data :

```
{"category_filter":["p1","p2"],"sub_category_filter":["p1|c1","p1|c2","p1|c3","p1|c1"]}
```

So basically the array structure is like this :

[image]

For now everything looks nice but, When I try to combine the array into once then it look some time to sort and rearrange itself, So it there any easy way to this, Each time I change the filters it will take time and then it fetch result from the database. For some reason I thought that **URL** which is custom made will help me but it only taking us to the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

apply condition in conrtoller like this

```
if($request->input('category_filter') == "p1"){
    
    if($request->input('sub_category_filter') == "p1|c1"){
        ... do your code as per your need
    }
    
}
```

I share Sample Example:
assume I want to filter data like All, approved, pending, decline... then I write script in controller like this

```
if($request->input('filtertype')){
     $filtertype = $request->input('filtertype');
     if($filtertype == "All"){
         $deals = Deal::orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get();
     }else{
         $deals = Deal::where('deal_isApproved', '=', $filtertype)
                       ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->get();
     }
}
   return view('admin.deals.index',compact('deals'));
```

Comment: Every Parent has same child then How to know that which child is belongs to which parent?